# Insisted that I come by

Tags: grammar

> A: Why are you home so late?
>
> B: **Jeff insisted that I come by for dinner.**

Is B's sentence grammatically perfect? Is 'come' correct even though B **has** been by Jeff's place for dinner?

Answer (score 3):

It's grammatical.

> Jeff insisted that X

X will talk about what Jeff insisted, so X is expressed from Jeff's point of view.  So use of *come* is appropriate.